# Mix server database with local database in your SSDT Database Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops, data-warehouse, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I have just started using SSDT Database project for version controlling my Sql Server DataWarehouse project using Azure Devops. The really cool thing is that it creates a local db to manage your database objects. But since I am working on datawarehouse project i can't load bulk of data locally in my db project especially for prestaging schema . So is there a way around to refer data from another physical database at least for prestaging schema but keep using db project to manage my dw schema tables and scripts (stored procedures). Actually when in my DW population scripts i need to refer to prestaging schema tables and they are empty locally. 
Any suggestions work around would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

are you using SSDT with Azure SQL Data Warehouse that's currently in preview? Note for Azure SQL Data Warehouse, localdb is not supported.

Comment: No. I am using SQL server on premise

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i found workable was to create views on the prestaging schema on actual on premise server db once with same name as tables instead of tables and exclude them from project it gets tricky when i need to work with new prestaging table. Luckily for me there are no changes required on prestaging table so it works out for me